# Текст в блоке

Tags: html

Обязательно ли текст, который лежит в каком-либо блоке, оборачивать в теги `<p>` или `<span>` ? или можно писать просто `<div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipi scing elit. </div>` Как правильно?

Comment: Обычно наоборот: текст помещают в блоки, а в блоке уже этот текст оборачивают в различные теги форматирования.

Comment: читайте внимательнее: *текст, который лежит в каком-либо блоке, оборачивать в теги <p> или <span>*

Comment: Всему свое SEO.  Тонкостей очень много, в том числе и сео продвижение имеет не мало отношения к тому или иному тегу. Но это так, ради заметки.

Ах да, по сути) нет не обязательно. Ответ @knes   вполне достойный.

Comment: спасибо за информацию, но пока интересует только с точки зрения правильности верстки)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С точки зрения верстки смотрите по-смыслу содержимого. Не совсем корректно поставлен вопрос :) Текст обязательно помещать в блок, но это не значит в div. Параграф так же является блоком. Заголовок, статья (p, article, h1-h6)и т.п. Span в свою очередь блочным элементом не является и его использование не только не обязательно, но и излишне. То есть спан не несет никакой смысловой нагрузки. Если какой-либо текст (или часть текста) ничем особенно не выделяется от своего окружения, но с ним надо что-то сделать (выделить цветом или как-то обозначит для манипуляции через javascript) то можно обернуть в спан. В случае ж с параграфом - используйте везде где подходит по смыслу - зачастую самый частый случай. Если используете тэги 5 хтмл - используйте article для смысловых едениц. Div так же не несет никакой смысловой нагрузки и его используйте когда нет более подходящего тэга.

Основная цель - текст должен быть обрамлен хотя бы в 1 блочный элемент. не важно будет это div или p. Если у вас уже есть div дополнительно можно не обворачивать в Р.

но естественно бывают и случае когда выгодно вложить параграфы внуть дива или статьи - если у вас большой текст с параграфами - вы каждый параграф выделяется тэгом P, а весь текст обворачиваете в div или article для стилизации целого текста или позиционирования его.

Comment: понятно, спасибо!)

Answer (score 3):

Можно не оборачивать. Но с обернутым проще работать в плане верстки. 
Вообще, если вам удается достичь правильного расположения и функционирования минимумом элементов - отлично. Не в ущерб гибкости, конечно.

Резюме: все норм, можно так. class="item" более чем достаточно.